# Check if an iLO board installed on a Windows machine

Tags: windows, hp, hp-proliant, ipmi, ilo

How can I check if a iLO-Board is installed on a Windowsmachine?
I would like to do it via a script (python prefered).

I thought about checking the connectionport. E.g.: If the iLO is connected via PCI, I can scan the PCI slots. But I couldn't find information about where it is connected.

Do you have any other ideas?
Thank you

Comment: 'How can I check if a iLO-Board is installed on a Windowsmachine?' - just check your up-to-date inventory control list that gets updated after every purchase and before deploying any hardware/software.  It should have this listed as one of the attributes/columns.  You do keep one of these, right?

Comment: Sorry, I think I can't follow you. Where can I find an inventory control list?

Comment: *swooooooooosh*

Answer (score 4):

The HP recommended way is to install the Proliant Support Pack for your operating system (regardless) with the HPONCFG and iLO Management Interface Driver.

Then run the `%Program files%\HP\hponcfg\hponcfg /a /w C:\ilo-config-output.txt` command to dump the complete ILO configuration to C:\ilo-config-output.txt. Then Python away.

Google for *"HP iLO 3 Scripting and Command Line Guide"* and check [www.hp.com/go/iLO3](http://www.hp.com/go/iLO3) for Sample ILO scripts as well.

Comment: I already tried some of the HP Programms. But I need to do it on multiple Machines, where I dont have the permissions to install programms. Is a iLO shown in the Device Manager? And if so, is there a way to access the Device Manager via a script?

Comment: If you're not one of the administrators what do you need the ILO information for? But on Linux the system command `dmidecode` would display the hardware specs, including the presence of ILO/IPMI cards and there seem to be [windows port](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/dmidecode/) as well.

Answer (score 3):

Some knowledge of your environment is necessary... It may be a silly exercise to even have to programmatically scan for this. It's like checking servers to see if a power button is present...

**MAKE SURE THE SERVER IS AN HP!!**

HP ProLiant 300, 500, 700-series servers from 2003 going forward have had ILO embedded onto the motherboard. Most 100-series HP servers have basic ILO facilities, too. If you're dealing with a modern server from HP, it likely has ILO capabilities...

Of course, that doesn't mean that ILO has been configured or even plugged in; a problem I see in many environments I walk into. So that's a different challenge.

For you, check the server model number; e.g. *"DL380 G6"* and cross-reference it with a Google of ["DL380 G6 quickspecs"](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=dl380%20g6%20quickspecs&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). You'll get ALL of the specification information you need there.

Answer (score 0):

Using Powershell you can find the basic information remotely from systems, as follows:

```
$g=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://$serverILONAME/xmldata?item=all";
$g.content;
```

Comment: Your answer lacks details. For this to work iLO must be configured and have network connectivity.